# MySQL max_connections of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, 20.04

I updated the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to include line `max_connections        = 65535`. I restarted the MySQL server with `sudo service mysql restart`. Then in the MySQL client I entered the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';` and got the following output:

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 9190  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried this on my desktop and on my dedicated server both running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I got the exact same results on both boxes.

What's going on? Why isn't the new `max_connections` value 65535?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage a connection , you need a file descriptor .

The `max-connections` will be constraint by the max open files .

So check the value of `open_files_limit`

```
show global variables like '%open_files_limit%'  ;
```

---

To change the value of `open_files_limit` to 20000 by example you must

1) run the command `systemctl edit mysql` and this

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=20000
```

2) `systemctl stop mysql`

3) `systemctl start mysql`